# JavaScript 'for in' statement giving unpredicted results

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have the following code:

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

if (screen.width > 640) {
    for (var image in images) {
        image = images[image];

        console.log(image['src']);
    }
}
```

There is only one image on the page, but for some reason the `for ... in` statement is looping through `images` three times. Why is this?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/OliverJAsh/C8egs/

Comment: How does this snippet of code get invoked?

Comment: For the purpose of this example, it is inline JavaScript on the HTML page.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the image variable used in the assignment with another name, I'm wondering if a conflict of the name could be occurring? I.E. you are using the var image in the for in, but then re-assign it, maybe try another variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not just looping through the list of elements, but also the named methods:

- `length`
- `item`
- `namedItem`

The correct approach is:

```
for (var i=0; i<images.length; i++) {
    var image = images[i];

    console.log(image['src']);
}
```

Instead of using `document.getElementsByTagName('img')`, you can also use [`document.images`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.images).

### http://jsfiddle.net/C8egs/2/

Comment: Very true, made [small test case](http://jsfiddle.net/6eCtb/) to demonstrate this.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I used `[i for(i in document.images)]` to confirm my list of named methods (So-called array comprehensions, currently supported in Firefox only).

Comment: @RobW Thank you, and thanks for the tip about `document.images`. It's time I started learning plain JavaScript instead of using jQuery all of the time, so that will come in use!

Answer (score 5):

`for(var x in var)` shouldn't be used for going through an array as it goes through the keys in the object.

If you do:

```
for (var image in images) {
        console.log(image );
}
```

You'll notice that the console output will show 'length' (as well as any other properties on the object);

Instead use it like:

```
for (var i=0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var image = images[i];

    console.log(image['src']);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The trouble is with your `for..in` loop. A `for..in` loop loops through all the enumerable properties of an object. `getElementsByTagName` returns a `NodeList`.  All `nodeList` objects have at least two additional properties besides the elements found: a `length` property, containing the number of elements found, and an `item` property, a method (following the DOM specification) to access elements numerically.

If you are looping through an array-like object, you should use a plain `for` loop instead:

```
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    console.log(images[i].src);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The looping is not three times actually it is looping four times. The looping differs in different browsers. I checked it in IE8 and FireFox
In fireFox it looped for four times and the console output is

- image node
- length
- item
- namedItem

In IE8 it looped twice

- length
- index position of the img tag

So you have to correct your for loop as shown below

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
if (screen.width > 640) {
    for (var i in images) {
        image2 = images[i];
        if(image2.nodeName == "IMG" || image2.nodeName == "img")
        console.log(image2['src']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

javascript's `for in` iterates the proprty of an object, not the content of the array. try this:

```
var obj = {"name": "one", "date": 10, "help": false};

for (var key in obj) {
    alert(key);
}
```

you have to resort for iteration by accessing the index of the item in the array.

```
for (var idx = 0, numImages = images.length; idx < numImages ; idx++) {
      image = images[idx];
      console.log(image['src']);      
}
```